# How to convert a column as date with special character?

Tags: r

In my dataframe I have a date column and I would like to convert it from character to date in the format d/m/y.

The head of my data:

```
head(df$date)
[1] [17/Jun/2019:08:33:49 [17/Jun/2019:08:38:20 [17/Jun/2019:08:38:24 [17/Jun/2019:09:52:42
[5] [17/Jun/2019:09:52:44 [17/Jun/2019:09:52:45
```

I used this but it converts every value into NA

```
df$date = as.Date(df$date, "[%d%b%y")
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the output of `dput(head(df$date))` into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `tidyverse` approach, looks like the `dmy_hms()` function accommodates that atypical first colon:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% mutate(date = dmy_hms(date), date = date(date))
```

Using your first value as an example:

```
date <- "17/Jun/2019:08:33:49"
date <- dmy_hms(date) 
date
#[1] "2019-06-17 08:33:49 UTC"
date <- date(date) #or all in one line, date <- dmy_hms(date) %>% date()
date 
#[1] "2019-06-17"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df$date <- strptime(df$date, format = "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your input

```
x <- c("[17/Jun/2019:08:33:49", "[17/Jun/2019:08:38:20",
        "17/Jun/2019:08:38:24", "[17/Jun/2019:09:52:42")
```

First convert it into `POSIXct` format and then to `Date`

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(x, format = "[%d/%b/%Y:%T"))
#[1] "2019-06-17" "2019-06-17" "2019-06-17" "2019-06-17"
```

or any other `format`

```
format(as.POSIXct(x, format = "[%d/%b/%Y:%T"), "%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "17/06/2019" "17/06/2019" "17/06/2019" "17/06/2019"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert into Date object try this.

```
df$date = as.Date(df$date,format="[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

If you want to retain time as well, then try the following.

```
df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date,format="[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

Best wishes.